# Button creates Timer, and Timer raises Tick event. How to get to the sender:Button from within Tick event?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-4.8

I have multiple buttons in my form and they all point to same events: buttonN_Click and buttonN_KeyDown. These buttons start listening for keyboard inputs with a countdown of 5 seconds. Key listening stops after 5 seconds. I wish to avoid hardcoding (button1.Text, button5.ForeColor etc.) as much as possible, so I pass senders around.

```
private void buttonN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    counter = 5;
    timer2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    timer2.Interval = 1000;
    timer2.Tick += timer2_Tick;
    timer2.Enabled = true;
    timer2.Start();
    button.KeyDown += buttonN_KeyDown;
}
```

```
private void buttonN_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    string keyPressedValue = e.KeyValue.ToString();
    if (CreateDictionary().ContainsValue(keyPressedValue))
    {
        button.KeyDown -= buttonN_KeyDown;
        e.Handled = true;
        counter = 0;
        string pressedKey = dictLookupByValue(keyPressedValue);
        string pressedValue = dictLookupByKey(keyPressedValue);
        string previousKey = getPreviousKey(button);
        string previousValue = getPreviousKey(button);

        writeXml(pressedValue, previousValue, previousKey, button);
    }
}
```

But in the _Tick event, where the majority of button manipulation takes place, i can't pass the sender:button because the _Tick event is raised by Timer, not button:

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    **var button = (Button)sender; // <- here is Type Cast Exception, naturally**
    counter--;
    button.Text = counter.ToString();
    if (counter <= 0)
    {
        timer2.Stop();
        timer2.Tick -= timer2_Tick;
        timer2.Enabled = false;
        button.Text = "Change " + Environment.NewLine + ReadIni(toggleKeyPrevValue) + " Hotkey";
        button.KeyDown -= buttonN_KeyDown;
    }
}
```

What I have in hand: Tick's sender, Timer. Is there any possibility to get the button that created Timer by using either _Tick or Timer inside the Tick event?

I tried to get to Timer's parent to no avail as it inherits Component, unlike Button, which inherits Control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need to invoke `timer2_Tick` in other places, you can move it into `buttonN_Click` as a [local function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions#c-language-specification), so that it can access `button` freely.

```
private void buttonN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    counter = 5;
    timer2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    timer2.Interval = 1000;
    timer2.Tick += timer2_Tick;
    timer2.Enabled = true;
    timer2.Start();
    button.KeyDown += buttonN_KeyDown;

    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter--;
        button.Text = counter.ToString();
        if (counter <= 0)
        {
            timer2.Stop();
            timer2.Tick -= timer2_Tick;
            timer2.Enabled = false;
            button.Text = "Change " + Environment.NewLine + ReadIni(toggleKeyPrevValue) + " Hotkey";
            button.KeyDown -= buttonN_KeyDown;
        }
    }
}
```